# iPhones and automatic 911 calls

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers

Can an iPhone6 automatically dial 911?  I was in a horrible traffic accident where I lost consciousness.  I obtained cell phone records and was surprised to find two 911 calls originating from my iPhone about the time of the accident.  I do not believe anyone else made the two calls (first call was 1 minute, second call was 3 minutes) and I feel certain that I did not.

Comment: Ask to hear the tape of the calls.  That's not your phone provider tho, you'll have to ask the police for 911 records, however it should be public record, so it should be obtainable.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, there is no function to automatically dial 911.
However, anyone with possession of an iPhone can dial an emergency call from the lock screen without unlocking the phone.

Whether that's more likely than you dialing and not remembering it (whether amnesia immediately following a trauma, or shock from the impact to your body or head is hard to guess as an outsider that wasn't there.